# Corona sdk large image becomes grey

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I tried to display a very large image in Corona sdk, 20000x1500.

```
bg = display.newImageRect("wbscene.png", 20000, 1500)
bg.x=-2050
bg.y=0
game:insert( bg )
```

The problem is that in the simulator, the image completely becomes a light grey color. How could I fix this?

Comment: This may be an issue with your system graphics card. I've tested the same with my mac. But there was no issue. Try it in a mac or a system with a good specification.

Comment: Hello, there is max image size for devices, for iPhone 3G is 2048x2048, for iPad 4096x4096 and for iPad retina 8192x8192 (I'm not 100% sure of the values). I think that is the reason that this might be happening.

Comment: @BrunoDomingues Ok, thanks! I just used an image half the size and scaled it up.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is larger than the maximum allowed by Corona SDK. Something that large would also rapidly eat into the mobile device memory.

For reference:

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newImage.html#gotchas
http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newImageRect.html#gotchas